# Is the fact that in-camera HDR was used available in EXIF metadata?

Tags: metadata, hdr

I have a Canon SX60, able to generate HDR pics.

I would like to know how can I detect a HDR image just checking the EXIF data, and if I can know about the different exposure details.

Comment: it would help if you just made a picture and posted it here, so we could have a look at its Exif.

Comment: I just posted (quite) same pic, normal version and HDR version. Links https://blog.jcea.es/hdr_NO.jpg and https://blog.jcea.es/hdr_YES.jpg. Help welcome!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your posted image, when inspected with [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), shows

```
Easy Mode                       : High Dynamic Range
Shooting Mode                   : High Dynamic Range
```

The exposure details are only for one of the exposures, of course.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I have upgraded my "exiftool" installation and I have asked for HDR support in the Python library I am using: https://github.com/ianare/exif-py/issues/48

Comment: Parsing an iOS 8 HDR picture with "exiftool" I get this tag: "HDR Image Type : HDR Image". So each vendor uses different tags. Messy :-(

Comment: funny. can a HDR image be any other type than a "HDR Image"?

Answer (score 3):

At least in some camera models it looks like Canon store the following in EXIF:

- HDR Shooting: Enable/Disable
- Adjust dynamic range: Enable/Disable
- HDR Effect: Natural/Art Standard/etc.
- Auto Image Align: Enable/Disable

What you see may depend on the tool you use.  The Canon software would most likely display it.  Not sure if Exiftool would.

One of the latter comments on a Lightroom Metadata plugin ([link](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/metadata-viewer)) mentions the above fields being shown by the Canon software for a 600D.

If you've done a single shot HDR image (in-camera) I suspect you won't see the range of values used in the shutter speed/aperture/ISO fields - probably just one value.

Comment: Pics posted!!. Help welcomed!.